# .htaccess causes 404 error

Tags: .htaccess

Morning Stackers,

I've recently inherited a website, I've moved the entire website over to the new server and tweaked the DB & Config URLs to point to the new location.

I think its the .htaccess as when I play around with it the index page works but none of the other pages do, Here is the current .htacess script (below) and here is the website Temp URL LINK-->http://83.170.113.94/~gagajool/ any suggestions on how to fix this problem would be great to hear.

Thank you

```
 RewriteEngine on
    Options FollowSymLinks

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^$
    RewriteRule ^(.+)$ / [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/static
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/favicon.ico

    RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$ /$1/ [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/static
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/favicon.ico

    RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php?request=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Can you explain briefly what you would like to achieve as rewrite rules? here I can see at least one possible problem cause, that is a duplicate RewriteCond set (it's not a problem in itself but it could be).

Comment: Tbh I'm just trying to get the website to display all pages, the .htaccess information above is what came with the website. Ive removed the duplication and all pages apart from index ain't showing.

Answer (score 0):

If the site is temporarily in a directory, the htaccess isn't going to work without accounting for the URI base.

For example:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

If the htaccess file is sitting in `/~gagajool/`, accessing `http://83.170.113.94/~gagajool/something` (notice the missing trailing slash) will cause the above rule to match, except the target is `/$1/`, so the browser gets redirected to `http://83.170.113.94/something/` (no more ~gagajool).

The same thing with the last rule (which is probably why you're getting a 404). Either add the correct URI base to your targets, e.g.:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$ /~gagajool/$1/ [R=301,L]
```

Or add a:

```
RewriteBase /~gagajool/
```

and remove the leading slashes from your rewrite rules:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$ $1/ [R=301,L]
```